# How to Use AWS Lambda To Tunnel Data From SQS Into Dynamo Considering WCUs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, data-processing

I have messages being put into SQS on a cron job at a rate of about 1,000 per minute.

I am looking to run a lambda function periodically, that will grab some of the messages and out them into dynamoDB with regards to the throughout which will changeover time.

Comment: How big is the typical message?  That will determine your WCU for DynamoDb.  Clarification question: Will you be processing all of the SQS messages and only sending some of them to DynamoDb?  If so, what percentage of these will go into DynamoDb?

Comment: All of them will eventually go to dynamo, I will be fetching thousands every five minute and if I send them all to dynamo from that lambda, then I would need to increase the WCU by quite a lot. messages are about 80bytes, so 1WCU will do.

Comment: Part 2) I use SQS so that I can add the store the messages upon fetching, then read from the queue to put the items into dynamoDB at a pace which I can afford.

Comment: Amazon charges per-hour for configured read and write capacity.  So 1 WCU supports 3,600 writes per hour.  So 1,000 per minute * 60 minutes = 60,000 in one hour.  60,000/3,600 = 16.67 WCU.   Source: https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/ search for "hour".  Is this reasonable for your use case?

Comment: That sounds good, I guess I could sacrifice lambda costs for dynamodb as lambda would be cheaper. So by running a lambda every 20 seconds and putting a rate limiter on it to write 20 seconds of data.

What do you think?

Comment: If you were to execute this using Cloud Watch Rules the best you can do is 1 Lambda execution per minute.  I'd start there, which would get you to 44,640 executions per month (60min*24hr*31days).  If you're using 128mb of allocated memory, the execution time is 60 seconds per execution, and you're not using the free tier then it would cost you $5.59 per month.  With free tier it would cost nothing.  If you are unable to handle the load in 60s then try upping the memory to see if that works.  If that doesn't work then there are other options like BatchWriteItem, etc...  I'd say experiment 1st.

Comment: Thanks Zaxxon, I will try using the cloudwatch cron job and try batchwriteitem if that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with 'OnDemand' pricing for your use-case. [AWS link](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/) The pricing is different that the provisioned capacity method.

> With on-demand capacity mode, you pay per request for the data reads and writes your application performs on your tables. You do not need to specify how much read and write throughput you expect your application to perform as DynamoDB instantly accommodates your workloads as they ramp up or down.

With this approach, you don't need to configure WCUs (or RCUs).